# How to calculate width & height of extended Rectangle

Tags: geometry, area

This is a mathematical formula based question, in image there is a rectangle with X width and Y height. Now I want to calculate the dimensions of a new rectangle with new width and height if I extend point A to point B. And the noticeable thing is that point B can be anywhere but the distance between point A and B is known. Help me.

[image]

Comment: Impossible unless you know something of the proportions. there's an entire of circle of points B can lie on at just knowing distance.

Comment: Ok , then what if the distance from all four points of rectangle and the point B is known??

Comment: 3 is enough. A point is uniquely determined by its distance from three other points.

Comment: @DavidPeterson , how to calculate then???, is there any formula

Comment: You have a simultaneous system: $$(x_1-b_1)^2+(x_2-b_2)^2 = d_1^2$$
$$(y_1-b_1)^2+(y_2-b_2)^2 = d_2^2$$
$$(z_1-b_1)^2+(z_2-b_2)^2 = d_3^2$$
where $(x_1,x_2), (y_1,y_2), (z_1,z_2), d_1, d_2, d_3$ are given numbers/points. Solve for $b_1, b_2$

Comment: here what will be the x1, x2, and so on . . . can you please elaborate

Comment: The first three are the three original points you know. The next three are the distances from those points respectively, that you know.

Comment: and what will be the b1 and  b2

Comment: The only exception to this rule is if one of the points lies at the center of a circle that the other three points lie on.

Comment: you need to solve it..

Comment: ok I'll solve it. but after solving the values what will they represent??? aren't you saying that b1 will be the width and b2 will be the height of new rectangle or something similar ???